# Cpanel and whm got hacked but

Tags: wordpress, server, cpanel, whm, whmcs

I have some subdomains running in all in wordpress. They worked fine but when I tried to install or delete or update any plugin, wordpress was showing me a message that i need to connect ftp and all info, which we didn't. Later I tried to login my cpanel whm, I got redirected back to a error page

```
Internal Server Error
500

Error ID 25356b0625763
cpsrvd Server at mydomain.test
```

What could possibly go wrong and how can I recover it?

And yes, I see hacker placed a text that they hacked it. In main site, there was nothing hosted, all were in subdomain..

Answer (score 0):

I've written some articles that specifically answer the question that you've asked about how to recover:

- https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360055310013-What-can-be-done-if-a-cPanel-account-is-compromised-
- https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360061360914-Is-it-possible-to-clean-malware-from-a-hacked-website-

As for what went wrong, that can be and is most often a very complex topic that requires a high level of expertise to properly and accurately diagnose.

That type of investigation would be risky and unreasonable to do via Stackoverflow due to the amount of identifiable server information that you'd need to provide.

I'd also like to mention that an account compromise occurs due to vulnerabilities in the websites and scripts hosted within the account and that those compromises will be contained within that individual cPanel account unless the attack were to make use of the symlink race vulnerability, which should be solved at the kernel level to be done properly:
https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/apache/symlink-race-condition-protection/

cPanel's Security Advisor will let you know about the status of the symlink race vulnerability on your specific server:

> WHM >> Home >> Security Center >> Security Advisor

There are no known vulnerabilities in cPanel or WHM that would allow for an account-level compromise to escape an account or allow a root compromise to occur.

If you suspect that you've discovered a zero-day vulnerability in cPanel or WHM, you should submit a ticket to cPanel support, as the issue would be taken very seriously.

However, the process of investigating and diagnosing the cause of an account-level compromise that came about due to a vulnerability in a website or script is something that a security specialist would be best equipped to take care of for you. Typically you'd want to seek out a Web Application Security Specialist.

As for the 500 error that you're seeing provided by cpsrvd (cPanel's webserver that handles requests for the cPanel, Webmail, and WHM interfaces) that is not likely related to the compromise. You can typically find more information about the cpsrvd 500 error by reviewing the cPanel error log at:
`/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log`

cPanel support would always be happy to assist with any 500 errors that you're experiencing on cpsrvd.